# Wire gauge for 15-pin SATA power cable

Tags: wire, sata

For two SATA SSDs I want to crimp one or two 15-pin SATA power cables with a length of about 30 cm (12 inch). Since space is a concern, I want to use cables thinner than AWG 16/17/18.

I know that SATA power cables can manage high currents, but this may be also due to historic reasons. Nowadays we have SSDs and the two SSDs (Samsung PM893) I want to use are rated with DC+5V at 1.3 A (= below 7 W) each.

Can I therefore assume that it is safe to only use AWG 23 for the 15-pin SATA power cable? Of course it will not burn, but could voltage drop be an issue?

Comment: Well, you could start by calculating how much voltage could drop through the wiring and connectors. Take also power supply output tolerance into account. The  compare that with SSD datasheet if it is still withing accepted range or outside it.

Answer (score 2):

23 AWG wire is about 66.8 Ω/km, for 20 mΩ over your 30 cm run.  18 AWG wire is about 20.9 Ω/km, which is 6 mΩ for 30 cm.  At 1.3 A, this equates to a voltage drop of 26 mV for the 23 AWG wire and 8 mV for the 18.  The difference is about 0.36% of the 5 V rail, or, to put it another way, 7.2% of the overall 5% of the allowable tolerance for the 5 V rail.  Will this be a problem?  Without knowing the input voltage tolerance of the SSDs and the accuracy of your power supply (probably a bit wider than 5% for the one, probably well within 5% for the other) it's hard to say, but probably not.  I would definitely run the system for a bit before putting it to work on anything really important.

Answer (score 0):

Just did some troubleshooting at home. I have two different types of hard drive trays, one 5X 3.5" and 8X 2.5" drive bays both which have two power connections on.  My 1200 watt power supply only has four 18AWG modular peripheral connections on my PSU.

My computer is very large and accommodates nine 5.25" bays with two 5.25" inside my case (11 total).

I installed a 6GB SAS controller and removed all my SATA drives and equipped my system with 7.2Krpm SAS, 10Krpm SAS and 15Krpm SAS.  My findings were that when using a single leg with two connectors to the drive bays, whenever more than three drives were utilized, the drives experienced intermittent failures.  If I added two separate legs, I was able to operate without error with the 7.2K and 10K drives.  When I acquired 15K drives, I found that I kept growing read errors on SMART and also when hot swapping drives, I would effectively brown out the +12Volt effectively resetting all the other drives in order to spin up the inserted drive.  I had to remove them all from the bay and make my internal drive setup whereby they all would be directly connected to the power supply.  Solved my issues, but still, I have many read errors recorded in SMART that are permanently caused by poor power delivery.

In the case of consumer electronics, 18AWG is fine, but when I custom make mine with 14AWG, I am not only able to connect more drives to a single leg (currently using 7 drives per leg) but I am also able to use the 15K drives without blue screens and drives dropping out on the array.

My observation is, if a Power supply is rated for 100Amp output, like mine which is equipped with a mere four peripheral legs, I am only able to deliver 16 of those AMPS to my hard drives which is hopelessly useless if I decide to connect 15 hard drives to my 16 port controller.  In hind sight, I do believe that these specifications on higher current power supplies should consider upgrading the gauges to at least 14AWG or more.  The Modular connections are also hopelessly weak AF, and I fried many of them in my time, even on my ATX connector on my mainboards. (Apparently using three 30 Watt GPU's fries motherboards if PCI-E power connections are not provided).

All in all, not very impressed with the addition of more failure points on the newer high powered power supplies.  I fail to understand why they are unable to utilize higher current rated connectors and higher current capable wires.  No matter, I void the warranties to make my power supplies do what I want.  I know how to solder them direct to the power supply circuit board and all my issues are gone.

My advice, use only 18AWG or bigger.  When mechanical drives spin up, they demand a inrush of current.  If you only have one SATA SSD drive, only then can you ever consider using 20AWG or smaller.  Kind of a no brainer, having a power supply that is only capable of delivering 16 Amps of steady current to your peripherals when it is rated to deliver 100 Amp is very very odd.  Might as well stick to 300 Watt power supply rated at 25Amp output.